# How to force 2 nested divs be carried together to new line

Tags: html, css, primefaces

I have auto generated HTML code by JSF.
I have 1 parent div with the number of nested spans and in each span i have 2 divs, one for label and one for input.
The problem is that one of inputs have a bigger width than others, so i want the span, which contains this input be rendered in new line. But it starts to render on first line and the input renders from new one. How to make them be together on new line?

I googled a lot, tried display: inline-block, white-space: nowrap, float: left and other css i found here and in web, but nothing helped.

```
<div id="block" class="ui-panelgrid-content ui-widget-content ui-grid ui-grid-responsive" style="padding-right: 10px">
    <span id="cell4" class="ort-cell id-cell">
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-1 ui-xl-1" style="display: flex;">
            <label>Label4</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 ui-xl-3">
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="cell5" class="ort-cell id-cell">
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-1 ui-xl-1" style="display: flex;">
            <label>Label5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 ui-xl-3">
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </span>
    <span id="cell6" class="ort-cell id-cell">
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-1 ui-xl-1" style="display: flex;">
            <label>Label6</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 ui-xl-5">
            <input></input>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Actual result is on screenshot, but i expect label6 to be with its input in new line, because size of input is bigger than other's.

[image]

```
@media screen and (min-width: 90.063em) {
.ui-xl-1 {
    width: 15.3333%;
}

.ui-xl-2 {
    width: 13.6667%;
}

.ui-xl-3 {
    width: 17.6667%;
}

.ui-xl-5 {
    width: 39.6667%;
}

.ui-xl-6 {
    width: 47.2222%;
}
```

}

Comment: can you please provide a snippet with css of what you've tried

Comment: Try replacing the span with div

Comment: @VarunRaval i have tried to do it exactly in the html code with style="***"

Comment: @omer tried that already, didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-1 ui-xl-1" style="display: inline-block;">
  <label>Label6</label>
</div>
<div class="ui-panelgrid-cell ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-4 ui-xl-5" style="display: inline-block;">
  <input></input>
</div>
```

Comment: display: inline-block to nested divs do not helps

Comment: please provide a snippet with css so I will check according to it

Comment: Added css for ui-xl classes. I have no other css for this